# Android TCP Socket

Tags: android, tcp, azure

I am trying to create a new TCP socket in Android emulator. Below is the Android code:

```
Socket s = new Socket("111.221.88.15", 8080);
```

But i keep getting UnknownHost Exception. I am able to create the connection in a windows C# application.

The site is a test project, developed in Microsoft Azure. URL:**http://tcptest24.cloudapp.net/**

I tried using the URL in place of IP address and various variants of it, but i keep getting the same error.

Hopefully ill get an early response as I am being charged :) and the site is of no use without client.

Thanks,
Anil

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add the `INTERNET` permission to your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: i think UnknownHost Exception isn't cause by permission. :)

Comment: From my sad experience it usually is.

Comment: @BinyaminSharet Thanks a lot... worked fine on including the permission.